# AWS "Certificate is in use" - How to disassociate certificate from ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate, load-balancing

I want to migrate a certificate `*.mywebsite.com` from region A to region B (my domain is hosted on Route 53).

To do so I deleted all resources bound to the certificate in region A (only API Gateway custom domain name). Then I tried to delete the certificate but a warning `Certificate is in use` tells me that the certificate is still associated with load balancers.

However, in EC2 > Load balancer, I have no load balancers left on the UI (nor security group, nor running instances).
I have tried to remove the load balancer from the error message by using :

```
aws --region ap-southeast-1 elbv2 delete-load-balancer --load-balancer-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-southeast-1:<account-id>:loadbalancer/<path-to-elb>/b22d537086da1807
```

That returns the error "must be in ARN format"

Any ideas on how I can remove these load balancers? Or how I can remove the certificate?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify. You wrote that you don't have load balancers, but later that you want to remove one? So which one is it? You have LB or not?

Comment: I don't have Load balancers on the UI (I checked in both region), but the error message says that I do.

Comment: I updated the message

Comment: Just create a new cert in the new region.

Comment: What's the output when you run these: `aws elb describe-load-balancers` and `aws elbv2 describe load-balancers` ? Do you see the ELBs listed?

Comment: I have the same problem, no load balancers in my account ("LoadBalancerDescriptions": []
)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you deploy a regional API endpoint, API Gateway creates an application load balancer (ALB) on your behalf. The load balancer is owned by API Gateway and is not visible to you. The ALB is bound to the ACM Certificate that you used when deploying your API. To remove the binding and allow ACM to delete your certificate, you must remove the API Gateway custom domain that is associated with the certificate.

You can fin this information on AWS Docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshoot-apigateway.html